# Show popup with binding on DataGrid row mouse over

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid, datatrigger

When a user hovers a row in a DataGrid I want to show a popup with some information about this row.
I've stuck how to bind DataTrigger to every row in dynamically populated DataGrid table.

I've found solutions only for tooltips but tooltips don't suit me because I need to have more control on popup (don't hide it immediately when a user moved a mouse cursor to another control, ability to click in popup with mouse etc.)

Here is XAML code where I'm trying to bind popup DataTrigger to every DataGrid row (I've put comments with questions in the code below)

```
<Window x:Class="VKPN.UI.Windows.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VKPN.UI.Windows"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <Popup Name="UserPopup" Placement="RelativePoint" HorizontalOffset="-5" VerticalOffset="0"
                                   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl}">
            <Popup.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Popup">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <!--How to specify binding to every DataGridTable row below?-->
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=DataGridTable, Path=???}" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Popup.Style>
            <Label>
                <Label.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <!--How to specify binding to every DataGridTable row below?-->
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=???}" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <!--DataGrid row has a column "id" which I want to show in the label. Did I do it correct below?-->
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=DataContext.id}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
                </Label.Style>
            </Label>
        </Popup>
            <DataGrid Name="DataGridTable" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Please help me to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Have you found some solution?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create 2 `AttachedProperty` called `RowPopup` and `ShowPopup`. 
   `RowPopup` will hold a reference to `Popup` control, and `ShowPopup` will show/hide this `Popup` based on `DataGridRow.IsMouseOver` property. These are extremely easy to implement.
2. Create a `Style` with TargetType `DataGridRow`.

Example,

> xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" x:Key="RowStyleKey">
       <Setter Property="local:CustomADP.RowPopup" Value="{Binding ElementName=Popup1}"/>
       <Setter Property="local:CustomADP.ShowPopup" Value="{Binding IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</Style>

<DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyleKey}" ... />
```

AttachedProperties Code :

```
public class CustomADP
    {
        /********* Set Popup to show ****************/

        public static Popup GetRowPopup(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (Popup)obj.GetValue(RowPopupProperty);
        }

        public static void SetRowPopup(DependencyObject obj, Popup value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(RowPopupProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RowPopupProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RowPopup", typeof(Popup), typeof(CustomADP), new PropertyMetadata(null));            

        /************* Show Hide using IsOpen property ************/

        public static bool GetShowPopup(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool) obj.GetValue(ShowPopupProperty);
        }

        public static void SetShowPopup(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ShowPopupProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ShowPopup. This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowPopupProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ShowPopup", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomADP), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(ShowPopupCallback)));

        private static void ShowPopupCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {         
            if (!(d is DataGridRow))
                return;

            if (((DataGridRow)d).IsFocused == true)
            {              
                Popup p = CustomADP.GetRowPopup(d);
                p.IsOpen = Convert.ToBoolean(e.NewValue);
            }
            else
            {
                Popup p = CustomADP.GetRowPopup(d);
                p.IsOpen = Convert.ToBoolean(e.NewValue);
            }
        }
    }
```